# Returning an uninitialised struct location

Tags: c, struct, tree, malloc

If I have some kind of tree, and I need to find a specific node in that tree which is essentially null (the struct is not initialised / malloc'ed yet).

If I want to return that very specific uninitialised struct place to be able to initialise it, would something like:

```
if (parentNode->childNode == NULL)
    return parentNode->childNode;
```

work? Or would it return NULL? Would I need to return the parent node instead?

The problem I have is that this specific node may be a child of multiple different struct types. I'm not sure how to overcome this in C, since it does not support generics. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @wildplasser yes I know I actually set it to NULL so I can know it is uninitialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return NULL. It will not be an identifiable location.

What you can do however is:

- `malloc` the node at the point where you find it and return the pointer returned by malloc,
- you can `return &(parentNode->childNode)` (a pointer to the childNode pointer) which the caller of 
  the function can use to set it to the new node, or
- `return parentNode`

I don't see how that problem could be mitigated by generics.

Answer (score 0):

You can return that `parentNode` and have its `child` initialized elsewhere.

Comment: The child's parent can be of different types. Therefore, I cannot return it unless I use void* - but that would be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can return NULL, but it would make no sense. You can return a *pointer* to the pointer whose value is NULL:

```
typedef struct link {
        struct link *next;
        } LL;


LL **getTailPP(LL **ppHead)
{
    for( ; *ppHead; ppHead = &(*ppHead)->next ) {;}
    return ppHead;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the child node is not initialised yet, then you cannot return a pointer to it... how can you return a pointer to something that doesn't exist yet??

What you need to do is return a pointer to the parent node's pointer, which can then be changed to point to the newly-allocated memory for the child node.

Comment: The child's parent can be of different types. Therefore, I cannot return it unless I use void* - but that would be problematic.

Comment: The child's parent's pointer to the child will always be of the same type, i.e. "pointer to child". So you can return that, which is what I'm suggesting.

`&(parentNode.childNode)` (note the dot instead of the arrow)